# javascript how to make spans table header?? lib ng2-smart-table

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-smart-table

I use a ***ng2-smart-table*** lib.

And I set like this:

```
settings = {
        hideSubHeader: true,
        pager: { perPage: 26, display: false },
        actions: false, 
        columns: {
            NO: {
                title: 'number',
            },
            name: {
                title: 'name',
            },
        },
    };
```

And I want to create new columns in 'name' header.

[image]

Comment: As per official docs there is no such functionality, you need to manually set the configuration. or go for another smart table may be Primeng's table is best for your use case

Comment: thank you for modifying my writing. I'm not skilled stackoverflow and english. And I will search Primeng's table. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per official docs, there is no such functionality, you need to manually set the configuration. or go for another smart table may be Primeng's table is best for your use case.

Refer here for Primeng Datatable -

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colgroup

Here you can easily use colspan and rowspan as per your requirements.